# here are more undefined behaviour in c++, sorry for this que[s]tion, but again UB

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

There is very simple UB example:

```
int i = 1;
i = i++; // classic example of UB.
```

I recently saw, how to use Pascal style `inc` operation. [Eric Niebler github](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)

```
// this structure little difference than original.
struct inc_t 
{   
  template< typename T> 
  T operator()(T& t ) const { return t++; } 
};

constexpr inc_t inc{};

//usage
int i = 1;
inc(i);
//or
int j = inc(i);
```

So, combine :

```
int i = 1;
i = inc(i); // Is there still UB ?
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe why there is not UB?

Comment: Can you explain why you believe there might be?

Comment: Well, I could if it was C++03. I'm trying to find the text for C++11 (or whether it changed).

Comment: @chris: if you don't need to quote the standard precisely, convert from C++03 to C++11 by replacing "there is a sequence point between X and Y" to "Y is sequenced after X" :-)

Comment: I don't believe there might be. I want know, this situation is UB or not, no more.

Comment: @SteveJessop, Did all of those actually stay the same? I know they added more non-UB (like `i = ++i`).

Comment: @chris: not in all cases, but if you're willing to go out on a (very strong) limb and guess that `i = inc(i);` is indeed defined behavior in C++11 then it's going to be for the same reason that it was in C++03.

Comment: You got the answer in the first comment. You asked a follow-up question, so clearly, you do want something more.

Comment: @SteveJessop, True enough.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: confidence that the answer is correct, I guess. The questioner *also* got an incorrect answer, but if every yes/no question resulted in one answer that said "yes" (and nothing else) and one that said "no" (and nothing else) then despite having the correct answer that would not help the questioner. Surely it goes without saying in any SO question that when you say, "I want the answer" you mean "I want a somewhat-supported answer"?

Comment: @Steve, "There is a sequence point between X and Y" can mean that "X is indeterminately sequenced with regard to Y" too. It does not mean "Y is sequenced after X". For example in `inc(i) + inc(j)`, there is a sequence point between the increment of `i` and the increment of `j`, but still `j` is *not* necessarily incremented after `i`!

Comment: Why do you even want to write `i = inc(i)`? The value of `i` will be the same as before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**.

`i = i++` is UB because it's not specified when `i` is incremented; it could be at any point after the *value computation* of `i++` (*i.e.*, lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of `i`) and before the end of the full-expression. Therefore this write is unsequenced with respect to the assignment statement. Two unsequenced writes to the same `int` is undefined behaviour.

But in `i = inc(i)` the incrementation of `i` occurs before the function returns, because the full-expression in which `t++` occurs lies inside the function. In turn, the function has to return before the value computation of the right-hand side, and the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of both sides. Therefore the incrementation of `i` is sequenced before the assignment, and there is no UB.

Relevant quotes from the C++11 standard:

§1.9/14

> Every value computation and side effect associated with a full-expression is sequenced before every value
>    computation and side effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.

§5.17/1

> In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value
>   computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression.

Comment: I don't see how these quotes are relevant.

Comment: @jrok the first one guarantees that the incrementation occurs before the function returns, and the second one guarantees that the function returns before the assignment occurs...

Comment: I beg to differ. The first ones guarantees that in `++i; ++j;` every side effect on i is complete before `++j;` runs. The second one says that in `E1 = E2;` both E1 and E2 are evaluated before asignment to E1 occurs. The two evaluations are unsequenced and that's why `i = ++i;` is UB. It does nothing to explain why `i = inc(i);` is OK.

Comment: The quote you want is: *When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline), every value computation and side effect
associated with any argument expression, or with the postﬁx expression designating the called function, is
sequenced before execution of every expression or statement in the body of the called function.* (1.9/15)

Comment: @jrok Now I don't see how *that* is relevant. The value computation associated with calling the function is trivial. The question is whether a side effect in the *body* of the function is sequenced before the value computation of the function call expression. And it is.

Comment: Ok, I see your point and agree about the second quote. But the first one still isn't relevant, IMO. The function call in `i = inc(i);` is not a full-expression.

Comment: @jrok, hmm, you might be right. I looked in the standard to try to understand what a full-expression or subexpression really is, but I couldn't find a clear definition of the latter. I suppose the incrementation is a subexpression of the full-expression `i = inc(i)`? Or is it? Anyway, I'm now actually not sure where in the standard to look... :/